# Chrome DevTools Dark Theme Visual Change/Bug?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Since the last Chrome update (85.0.4183.83|macOS Mojave - 10.15.5) DevTools dark theme is looking a bit odd (screenshoots below). Are you experiencing the same thing?
[image]

Before it used to be like this (taken from Chrome Canary 87.0.4248.0):
[image]

I know this is a very small thing, but IMO it's worse than before and these changes are only with the dark theme.

Comment: Simply report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I've reported it on chromiumbugs.com but it's not fixed yet :(